# I need help using geolocation on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, geolocation

Im running wordpress with a very light theme so I have room to play. Basically I need to be able to display location specific posts and custom posts when a user visits the site. Like say if one were visiting from Maine, the sites posts would be completely different content than say Los Angeles' content. Thoughts? Help getting there? I've done research and I'm at a roadblock so I came here.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too much into the code, I would suggest using something like WPGeocode: You can use shortcodes to change the content based on different variables:

http://wpgeocode.com/

There are a few examples on the website, but the plugin is pretty trivial to set up if you are familiar with the use of shortcodes in your template files.

Comment: Thank you. Im currently using geocode  but am unclear on how I'd get it to apply to Posts themselves.